# Vue3 component registration issue is the app.js

Tags: vuejs3

I am trying to register component in app.js for VUE 3 app as below:

```js
import test1 from './components/test1.vue';
import test2 from './components/test2.vue';

createApp(test1).mount("#app").default;
createApp(test2).mount("#app").default;
```

But it's giving error as below. If I display only one component then it works fine.

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nextSibling' of null
    at nextSibling (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:35)
    at removeFragment (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5719)
    at remove (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5685)
    at unmount (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5671)
    at unmountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5743)
    at unmount (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5644)
    at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4642)
    at render (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5791)
    at mount (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4081)
    at Object.app.mount (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:1319)
```

I am accessing it in the template as below:

```html
    <div id="app">
                <test1>
                    <test2></test2>
                </test1>
    </div>
```

Could anyone advise how can I get rid of this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To register a component, use the `App.component` method instead of `createApp` which is meant to create a new Vue instance. Normally you would have something like the following:

```js
const app = createApp(...)

app.component("test1", test1)
app.component("test2", test2)

app.mount('#app')
```

You can read more about component registration [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-registration.html#component-names).

Comment: Thanks. It worked by creating a new Vue instance when registering the components.